# Change image on click of colored button

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am helping out a friend with his site and he would like to be able to change a image on the click of certain colored buttons, i have tried working with data-color and getting the attribute and checking but it mostly does not work and as a hard fix I created a bad set of code where i function each check for every single color, i'd like to know if it's possible to do this in one function and easily or more easier than i'm doing it atm haha!

Code:
Here i ask the user to chose a color and the check

```
<h2> kies een kleur</h2>
<a href='#' onclick='red()'><div class="red colorChoose" data-color = 'red'> 
</div></a>
```

And here i replace the image:

```
<div class="imageLook"><img alt="image" id="imageReplace" 
src="image location"></div>
```

And for Javascript

```
function red()
{   
    if (document.getElementsByTagName("div")[2].getAttribute("data-color") == "red" ){       
        document.getElementById("imageReplace").src="image location";
    }
}
```

js fiddle with the code, it doesn't work at all there so i don't kwow if it's a huge help... sorry for people who put a lot of effort into this issue. huge thanks! https://jsfiddle.net/ft5b8w9a/

Thanks for all the help and feedback!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Try to make a JSFiddle contain your working code until now...

Comment: So at this moment if i put them into an else if it always takes the last if as the right image although the button clicked is another one  like if i press red and the last if in the function is an else if for blue it gives me the image for blue and ignores the check for red. I'd like to know how to get it to properly check the data-color attribute so it would give me the image for the red button not the blue one so the check would work, Hope this clarifies it a bit more

Comment: Something like this? 


    document.body.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        if (event.target.getAttribute("data-color") === "red") {
            //change image here
            debugger;  
        }
    });

Comment: Yupp something like that! I added in a Js fiddle showing the code i have at this moment so i hope it gives a better view on what i want to do!, This is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ft5b8w9a/

Comment: You can do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ft5b8w9a/1/ pass current/clicked element as function argument, and, when you get data-color variable, switch-case with it, or something similar.... Actually, for changing of images - add image url's as data attributes.... (if you need to keep colors, you can make additional data attributes with image urls)

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys i fixed it now! Lot of thanks for the quick help and aswers, if i can help any of you out in the future i sure will! thanks to all who commented!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to use the filename in place of the color name.

```js
var img = document.querySelector( 'img' );
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll( 'button' );

// Use an object as a dictionary to map a color to a filename.
var basePath = 'path/to/img/';


// Add event listener is JS not in the HTML.
for ( var i = 0, len = buttons.length; i < len; i++ ) {

  var btn = buttons[ i ];
  
  btn.addEventListener( 'click', function ( e ) {
    var file = basePath + this.getAttribute( 'data-file' );
    img.src = file;
    img.alt = file;
  } );
  
}
```

```html
<img src="path/to/img/default.jpg" alt="path/to/img/default.jpg">

<h2>Colors</h2>
<button data-file="apple.jpg">Red</button>
<button data-file="cloud.jpg">White</button>
<button data-file="sky.jpg">Blue</button>
```

If for some reason you really want the color name, then I might create a *"dictionary"* that maps a color option to a file.

```js
var img = document.querySelector( 'img' );
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll( 'button' );

// Use an object as a dictionary to map a color to a filename.
var basePath = 'path/to/img/';
var colorToFile = {
  'red': 'apple.jpg',
  'white': 'cloud.jpg',
  'blue': 'sky.jpg'
};

// Add event listener is JS not in the HTML.
for ( var i = 0, len = buttons.length; i < len; i++ ) {

  var btn = buttons[ i ];
  
  btn.addEventListener( 'click', function ( e ) {
    img.src = basePath + colorToFile[ this.getAttribute( 'data-color' ) ];
    img.alt = basePath + colorToFile[ this.getAttribute( 'data-color' ) ];
  } );
  
}
```

```html
<img src="path/to/img/default.jpg" alt="path/to/img/default.jpg">

<h2>Colors</h2>
<button data-color="red">Red</button>
<button data-color="white">White</button>
<button data-color="blue">Blue</button>
```

Overall, I would avoid adding event handlers in your HTML if you can help it (i.e. `<a onclick="function()">`).

Comment: Thanks for the help! this is how I wanted it! Thanks! i marked you as the solution for mine! A Big +1!

Comment: You could also make it ARIA-supporting using aria-* and role attributes. I created a sample on how to do that: https://jsfiddle.net/flaviocysne/jrh3z6tL/

Comment: @FlavioCysne beyond the scope of the question, lol. But, yeah.